# Hierarchy implementation of the visitor pattern in C++

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I have a class structure defined like so:

```
class Pet {};
class Dog : Pet {};
class Cat : Pet {};
```

On this class structure i am implementing the visitor design pattern, with something like this:

```
class Pet {
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
class Dog : Pet {
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
class Cat : Pet {
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
class Visitor {
    virtual void visit(Pet*)=0;
    virtual void visit(Dog*)=0;
    virtual void visit(Cat*)=0;
};
class ConcreteVisitor : Visitor {
    virtual void visit(Pet*) {
        std::cout<<"Pet"<<std::endl;
    }
    virtual void visit(Dog*) {
        std::cout<<"Dog"<<std::endl;
    }
    virtual void visit(Cat*) {
        std::cout<<"Cat"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

With a class structure defined like this, if i write call, for example

```
Dog dog;
ConcreteVisitor v;
dog.accept(v);
```

It will print `dog`. Now my question is: how could i call the visitor on `Pet` class (the base class) after the printing of dog? I need to accomplish this **without** explicit call it in the ConcreteVisitor class. i do this because the implementation of the Visitor (like ConcreteVisitor) is for me out of control (who use my code extends the `Visitor` to do anything with my class structure) and they could not call the visitor on the base type.
Excuse me for my bad english and thank you in advice for your answers.

Comment: You need a reference or pointer to a `Pet` class, a reference or pointer that is actually a `Dog` instance. Also, you don't need an implementation of `Accept` in the `Pet` class, that function can (and should be) abstract as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg maybe with something like (Pet*)dog ? and where should i put this code?

Comment: how can you pass object of `ConcreteVisitor` as an argument , when the function accepts only `Visitor`

Comment: Agree with balaji, ConcreteVisitor should inherit from Visitor

Comment: Excuse me, i have edited the classes

Answer (score 1):

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

```
Dog dog;
Pet* pet = &dog;

ConcreteVisitor v;
pet->accept(v)
```

Comment: You could put it in your `int main()` function

Comment: i can't put your answer in the main() because i could not have a main() function, think at my code as a library that someone will use

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dog dog;
Pet& pet = dog;

ConcreteVisitor cv;
Visitor& v = cv;

pet.accept(v);
```